# LLVM - What optimizations frontend has done

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-gcc, llvm-ir

I know that frontend (such as llvm-clang or llvm-gcc ) has also done some optimizations from native code to IR level.

But what's optimizations that frontend has done ? Is there a list or a document I can check.

Thanks.

Comment: You will have to ask the developers of those frontends. They also implement language-specific optimizations either before or during lowering to IR, such as RVO/NRVO.

Comment: Thanks. Let us see if someone may know the answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print all the passes which the code goes through by using:

`clang -O2 -Rpass=.* code.cc -o code`

This will also print the information from each of the optimization passes that were used to process the code when `O2` level is used with `clang`, for example.

See this link for more details: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#options-to-emit-optimization-reports